# get the elevation of a googlemaps' marker

Tags: google-maps, elevation

I try to get the elevation of a point on a map, but the elevation function proposed by the googlemaps' API doesn't work and I don't know why.
It seems that the programm don't even get through the function.

Here my function :

```
var elevationService = new google.maps.ElevationService();

var requestElevation = {
'locations': gmarkers[0].getPosition()};

elevationService.getElevationForLocations(requestElevation, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
  if (results[0]) {
    document.getElementById('denivele_circuit').value = parseFloat(results[0].elevation.toFixed(1)) + "mètres";
  }
}  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get a javascript error with your code: `Uncaught InvalidValueError: in property locations: not an Array`

The `locations` property in the [LocationElevationRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LocationElevationRequest) must be an array.

> [from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LocationElevationRequest) for **google.maps.LocationElevationRequest object specification**

> An elevation request sent by the ElevationService containing the list of discrete coordinates (LatLngs) for which to return elevation data.

> **Properties**

> **locations** Type:  **Array**

> The discrete locations for which to retrieve elevations.

```
var requestElevation = {
  'locations': [gmarkers[0].getPosition()]
};
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/233c1z48/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var gmarkers = [];

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map
  });
  gmarkers.push(marker);
  var elevationService = new google.maps.ElevationService();

  var requestElevation = {
    'locations': [gmarkers[0].getPosition()]
  };

  elevationService.getElevationForLocations(requestElevation, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]) {
        document.getElementById('denivele_circuit').value = parseFloat(results[0].elevation.toFixed(1)) + " mètres";
      }
    }
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<input id="denivele_circuit" />
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```